# why wxScreenDC get black screen

Tags: c++, debian, screenshot, wxwidgets

Does anyone know why **wxScreenDC** only get **black screen** when Blit to a wxMemoryDC.
I'm using Debian system with ***wxWidgets v3.1.5(or v3.1.6)***
Same code, replace **wxScreenDC** with **wxWindowDC** everything go fine.
This is my code:

```
void MyFrame::OnCapture(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxFileDialog dlg(this, _("Save PNG file"), "", "",
                       "PNG files (*.png)|*.png", wxFD_SAVE|wxFD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT);

    if (dlg.ShowModal() == wxID_CANCEL)return;

    wxScreenDC dc;
//  wxWindowDC dc(this);
    wxSize sz = dc.GetSize();
    wxBitmap bmp(sz.x, sz.y);

    wxMemoryDC memDC;
    memDC.SelectObject(bmp);
    memDC.Blit(0, 0, sz.x, sz.y, &dc, 0, 0);
    memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
    bmp.SaveFile(dlg.GetPath(), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
}
```

Comment: why are you painting outside paint event?

Comment: Oh, I didn't intend to draw on the screen. I'm going to take a screenshot after the user clicks the [Capture Screen] button